# Selenium - Open multiple links in NewTabs

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am using Python 3.7.2, installed Selenium using PIP. I am on Windows 10 1809 machine. I am using chromedriver. I am able to use the sample code from the documentation. So far I was able to open the site and do the search but I am stuck at below obstacle (for me) and I am not able figure out how to loop through the list of the links to open.

Below code is for the Single List item. When I click on the title it opens up the page.

```
<a class="clickable" style="cursor:pointer;" onmousedown="open_listing_detail('abcd321', '0', false)" title="View Listing Detail" key="abcd321">Some xyz Listing </a>
```

There are about 20 items in each page. I need those 20 items to be opened up in NewTabs.

If not then I would like to Open the link -> grab the information from the page -> close the page -> Open the second link -> repeat

To Move to the next page I need to click on the next button. For that element below is the code.

```
<li key="2" class="pageLink page">Next</li>
```

I am novice at Programming/Scripting. Let me know if you need any further details to clarifying my query.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!   Please familiarize with this FAQ and repost your question -- How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example - https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcv

Comment: @Life is Complex, When I click on the link i am redirecting to Page not found

Can you please let me know what needs to be modified or what is missing. I would like to know why repost is necessary.

I got the page. "e" is missing from url you have provided. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: thanks for point that out.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, If I understand your query correctly here is the solution.

```
# iterate while next button is enabled
while (driver.find_element_by_xpath("//li[@class='pageLink page' and .='Next']").is_enabled()):
    # get all the links in the current page
    links  = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[@class='clickable' and contains(@onmousedown,'open_listing_detail')]")
    baseURL = driver.current_url
    # open the link and perform operation in new tab
    for link in links:
        # click on link
        link.click()
        print(driver.title)
        print(driver.current_url)
        #close the tab
        # click on back
        driver.back()
        # alternatively you can use the url
        #driver.get(baseURL)
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//li[@class='pageLink page' and .='Next'].click()
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply.

Your code has worked partially. When I run the code it is opening the first link only in the same window. Is it possible to Open each link in NewTab and keep the MAIN page which contains the list items.

I am getting the following error after the script ran.

`code`
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Software\projects\rp.py", line 31, in <module>
    print(driver.url)
AttributeError: 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'url'
`code`

Please let me know if you need any more details.

Comment: Can you please keep a break point at `link.click()`, and do  it in debug mode. I suspect we should add some `time.sleep(5)` or wait until the new tab open. Do it in debug mode, make sure to wait until the tab is opened completely before stepping out. You should see the new tab selected, when `driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[-1])` line executed.

Comment: I have set the break point at `code` link.click() `code` 

I have got the below following error. First link is opening in the same window which contains the 20 list items (main page)

`code`
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Software\projects\rp.py", line 25, in <module>
    link.click()
`code`

Comment: Updated the answer, try with new code. I thought clicking link will open the new tab. You should be good now.

Comment: Thank you very much for your effort. The only problem here is not looping through the 20 links. Opening the first link and coming back to main page.

Comment: hmm. If you don't mind I will jump back after 3 hours.

Comment: Yes, the logic here is to click on the first link which will open in the same browser. Then click on back in browser, which will take you back to main page and then clicks on second link once all the links are done 20 links are done on the first page then it will click on `Next` button and the iterate for all 20 links. This will go until the Next button is disabled. check the last line that I added to click on Next button.